# Trying to average a substring that is data type varchar

Tags: sql, int, varchar

I would like to select the average of a numerical substring within a column defined as varchar.  A mass conversion does not work because there is some data in this string that contains non-numeric characters.  I would like to ignore these non-numeric strings.

My query looks something like this:

```
select i.location, avg(convert(int,substring(b.text,8,4)))
from item i, bib b
where i.bib# = b.bib#
and b.tag = '008'
group by i.location
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Have you tried using ISNUMERIC() on your field substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select i.location, avg(convert(int,substring(b.text,8,4)))
from item i
join bib b on i.bib#=b.bib#
where b.tag = '008'
and isNumeric(substring(b.text,8,4))=1
group by i.location
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!  I was trying to squeeze ISNUMERIC into the select statement earlier, which obviously did not work.